# Sensitivity, Specificity

Tags: r

While calculating sensitivity, the predicted value which is used as one of the argument in the sensitivity function is not being calculated.

The actual value which is also used as an argument in the sensitivity function has already been  calculated using the same data.
The actual value has been calculated using the function
`y_act<- Testing$Recommendation`
Since this syntax is used to calculate the Sensitivity
`Sensitivity(actuals, predictedScores, threshold = 0.5)`
and in this syntax the actuals have been calculated easily. Tell me the procedure to calculate PredictedScores.

```
y_act <- testing$Recommendation

> pred <- predict(fit,newdata = testing, type = "response")
Error in match.arg(type) : 
  'arg' should be one of “vector”, “prob”, “class”, “matrix”
y_pred <- ifelse(pred  >0.5 ,1, 0)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(pred, 0.5) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

Error in match.arg(type) : 
  'arg' should be one of “vector”, “prob”, “class”, “matrix”
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(pred, 0.5) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56254635/edit), it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type` argument should be set to `prob`. This will make your output a probability as opposed to a binary class response, which is necessary for calculating sensitivity and specificity since those vary over all probability thresholds.

Comment: pred <- predict(fit,newdata = testing,type="prob")
> y_pred <-ifelse(pred >0.5,1,0)
> y_act <-testing$Recommendation
> mean(y_pred==y_act).. After running these commands I have got the output. The next error is the following:-
> library(caret)
> caret::confusionMatrix(y_pred,y_act,positive="1",mode="everything")
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
Please suggest the solution for the same now.

Comment: > pred <- predict(fit,newdata = testing,type="prob")
> y_pred <-ifelse(pred >0.5,1,0)
> y_act <-testing$Recommendation
> mean(y_pred==y_act)
[1] 0.5
> sensitivity(y_pred,y_act)
Error in sensitivity.default(y_pred, y_act) : inputs must be factors

Comment: `Error: data and reference should be factors with the same levels` means that the levels for one of your factor columns are not the same. By that, I mean hat if you have a column `A` with factors `x`, `y`, `z`, column `A` on your reference dataframe probably has factors `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`. 

For the second error, make sure that `y_pred` and `y_act` are factors. If they are not, you can coerce them to be with `as.factor()`

Also, please re-structure your posts so that they're a bit easier to read, otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: > pred <- predict(fit,newdata = testing,type="prob")
> y_pred <-as.factor(ifelse(pred >0.5,1,0))
> > y_act <- as.factor(testing$Recommendation)
> mean(y_pred==y_act)
[1] 0.5  //THIS HAS BEEN DONE RIGHT
> caret::confusionMatrix(y_pred,y_act,positive="1",mode="everything")
Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
  all arguments must have the same length... How can this error be resolved?

Comment: Your two data frames do not have the same length. If your reference table has `X` columns and `Y` rows, your test table must also have `X` columns and `Y` rows. From your error, it looks like the columns `X` do not match in length (i.e, you have `X` columns in table 1, but `Z` columns in table 2).